# jQuery loop through set of divs, one at a time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am building a wordpress onboarding plugin.

I have an array that contains the content for each step of onboarding process, then a function that outputs each step in it's own container, with it's own class:

```
static function action_build_steps() {
    $items = Onboarding_Dashboard::dashboard_onboarding_content();
    $output = '';
    foreach ($items as $step => $item) {

        // Classes
        $step_class = array();
        $step_class[] = str_replace("-", "", $step);
        $step_class[] = (isset($item['class']) ? $item['class'] : NULL);
        $step_class = implode( ' ', $step_class  );

        echo '<div id="onboarding_steps_container" class="'.$step_class.' onboarding-'.Onboarding_Setup::onboarding_slug().'" style="left:'.$item['left'].'; top:'.$item['top'].'; width:'.$item['width'].';">';
        echo '<div class="onboarding_steps">';
        echo '<h2>'.$item['title'].'</h2>';
        echo '<p>'.$item['content'].'</p>';
        if(isset($item['css_arrow'])) {
        echo '<div class="arrow_'.$item['css_arrow'].'"></div>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="button_holder">';
        if (($item['show-prev'])=='true') {
        echo '<button id="prev" class="'.$step_class.'"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i> PREV</button>';
        }
        if(($item['show-next'])=='true') {
        echo '<button onboarding_stage="dashboard" id="next" class="'.$step_class.'">NEXT <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>'; 
        }
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }

    return $output;
}
```

This results in showing ALL steps at once, however, the plan is to show one step at a time, and when the user clicks "Next" or "Prev" they see the next or previous step.

I know I need to do this using jQuery but can't think how I will do it, mainly because I have a dynamic number of steps - it's not a set number.

So far, I have just hidden all steps using this script:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.onboarding-<?php echo Onboarding_Setup::onboarding_slug(); ?>').hide();

    });
```

My outputted html looks a bit like this (I'll take out the content)

```
<div id="onboarding_steps_container" class="step1  onboarding-dashboard" style="left:50%; top:320px; width:500px;">

    <div class="button_holder">
        <button onboarding_stage="dashboard" id="prev" class="step1 ">NEXT <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
        <button onboarding_stage="dashboard" id="next" class="step1 ">NEXT <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="onboarding_steps_container" class="step2 onboarding-dashboard" style="left:50%; top:320px; width:500px;">

    <div class="button_holder">
        <button onboarding_stage="dashboard" id="prev" class="step2 ">NEXT <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
        <button onboarding_stage="dashboard" id="next" class="step2 ">NEXT <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where you see the word 'dashboard' in the script above, that is also dynamically added depending on the page the user is on. Also, the first step doesn't have a previous button, and the last step doesn't have a next button (they do in my code above, but just for demonstration)

How would I iterate through each step, 1 at a time, hideing the previous step, then showing the next?

UPDATE:
Here is what I've managed to come up with so far:

```
jQuery(function($) {
            var index = 0;
$(function() {
  $('.onboarding_steps_container:not(:first)').hide();
  $('#next').click(function() {
    if (($('.onboarding_steps_container').length - 1) >= index) {
      $('.onboarding_steps_container:eq(' + index + ')').hide();
      index++;
  $('.onboarding_steps_container:eq(' + index + ')').show();
  }
});
$('#prev').click(function() {
if (index != 0) {
  $('.onboarding_steps_container:eq(' + index + ')').hide();
  index--;
  $('.onboarding_steps_container:eq(' + index + ')').show();
}
});
});
```

I think my issue is that each step has a different button (even though the ID is the same a referenced in my script)
            });

However, this only works for the first button click, no others

Here's a JSFiddle showing my situation:
https://jsfiddle.net/fwysy2rr/

Comment: aha, got it, just need to change my selectro to button#next and button#prev

Answer (score 0):

Make a function in javascript call onclick on next btn

```
var current_div =1; 

function showDiv(var i){
 //first hide all div having class  onboarding-

//show next div
$(".step"+current_div+1 + "onboarding-dashboard");

//set current div 
current_div +=1 ;


}
```

Comment: Couldn't get this idea to work - i've added a jsfiddle to my description with my latest code https://jsfiddle.net/fwysy2rr/

Comment: hii i chnages some code in your fiddle and its working now for next btn call

https://jsfiddle.net/fwysy2rr/6/
hope you noe got the idea what to do and how to do 
select my answer if new updated fiddle do what you want .